Is it true that before European modernity, there were no "nations"?
Some authors point that "nation" is a social construct. Below (MacDonald 1989, p. 8) is an example (the author uses "nation" as meaning "country"):

Nations are units of identity and organization which found their modern form in the last two hundred years or so of European thought. They are creations. This applies as much to the relatively well-established nations of Europe as it does to those areas of the world to which Europe's ideas of nationhood have been exported more recently. Nations are not natural and self-generating units, or the emergence or re-emergence of atavistic forces of blood, soul, or territory.

"Nation" can have various definitions. Here is how my question refers to it, based on this official document: a nation is a kind of society defined and organized around a common government which enacts common rules (i.e. a more or less centralized state), a common language and a common culture, over a common territory, which give this society its unity.
It is the Enlightenment and the French revolution which crystalized this reality as a more coherent and explicit political notion and idea.
Apparently, this exact type of society emerged primarily in France and England, so the concept that captures this reality (the concept of "nation") is not necessarily applicable in other regions of the world exactly as how it is defined by French Enlightenment and revolutionary figures for instance.
Nevertheless, I have difficulty not to recognize, roughly, nations in the world before the European modernity (i.e., the Enlightenment and the French revolution).
The Berber Kingdoms, the Hungarian Kingdom, the Japanese Tokugawa shogunate, the Kingdom of Castile, the Chinese Empire, to me fit more or less loosely the definition of nation provided above.
Certainly the advance of the print, of territory-internal commercial exchanges, etc. promoted higher identity unity (language, values, etc.). Or otherwise, historical factors prompted neighboring peoples to accelerate the pace of construction of a centralized state (e.g. Germany, Italy).
NB: This question was asked in the Philosophy SE, but closed because not fitting the forum. Also I improved the quality of my question by synthesizing the idea behind it.
References:
McDonald, M. (1989). “We are not French!”: Language, Culture and Identity in Brittany. London and New York: Routledge.

This is probably more suitable for H.SE.

My question is influenced by Mark Moffett's work ""A society is a group extending beyond an immediate family, capable of perpetuating its population for generations, whose members ordinarily perceive one another as belonging together and set apart from other groups (notwithstanding transfers between societies, either mutually agreeable or initially forced) and which regulates access to a space or spaces it ultimately controls, across which its members travel with relative impunity" (Moffett 2024, 13)."

VTC. Suggest migration to History.SE. See Cutoff between Politics and History.

I answered a similar question in Philosophy stack, and I don't want to take the effort of duplicating it here unless you think it's a worthwhile perspective.  Let me know.

@TedWrigley The question was closed on Philosophy SE, while I didn't have the sentiment that the conversation was over. Indeed, reopening it on the Politics SE also provide another perspective.

I don't understand how this belongs to SE Politics. Is it not far more suited to History or Language, for instance?
Either way, what difference might it make whether the English of 1,000 or 500 years ago saw themselves as a 'nation' as opposed to a 'country' or 'kingdom' or 'realm'?

You named Hungarian Kingdom which in premodern times did not really have common language. Latin was used in official and church capacity.

This question definitely belongs here. The sovereign status of nations pertains to politics. OP might want to mention the Peace of Westphalia regarding European modernity as that is an uncontroversial (not a Western conceit) and clearly political reference point.

First, this does sound, a lot, like a certain brand of Western conceit.  Obviously, there were countries before and that is almost a synonym for nation.  Political units existed, had a defined territory, raised taxes and fought wars.
If not nations, then what would those be?
Nation

a country, esp. when thought of as a large group of people living in one area with their own government, language, and traditions:

Consider that its roots in Western languages, are old:

c. 1300, nacioun, "a race of people, large group of people with common ancestry and language," from Old French nacion "birth, rank; descendants, relatives; country, homeland" (12c.) and directly from Latin nationem (nominative natio) "birth, origin; breed, stock, kind, species; race of people, tribe," literally "that which has been born," from natus, past participle of nasci "be born" (Old Latin gnasci), from PIE root *gene- "give birth, beget," with derivatives referring to procreation and familial and tribal groups.


The word is used in English in a broad sense, "a race of people, an aggregation of persons of the same ethnic family and speaking the same language," and also in the narrower sense, "a political society composed of a government and subjects or citizens and constituting a political unit; an organized community inhabiting a defined territory within which its sovereignty is exercised."


In Middle English it is not easy to distinguish them, but the "political society" sense emerged by 16c., perhaps late 14c., and it has gradually predominated. The older sense is preserved in the application of nation to the native North American peoples (1640s).

However - besides providing the professional opportunity for intellectuals to carry out the modern equivalent of arguing about how many angels can dance on a the head of a pin - "European modernity" did modify the term from late 18th century onwards.
Before the US and French revolution, while there was such a thing as nations, to a large extent they were defined by their rulers and the masses of people were, if drawn together by language and customs and xenophobia, not entirely invested in "their" grouping which really was decided by their local ruler whom they had very little to say about.
Places like Italy and Germany had those common customs, for example, but were fragmented in "nations" that were just local fiefdoms.
One could argue a place like the UK already had a much stronger feel of togetherness, but then again, they also had a proto-democracy going on for centuries and being an island were a bit special.
But there are also strong signs of nationhood elsewhere.  Look at the Khmer Empire.  That seems like a lasting togetherness. What is that if not a "nation"?  Or places like the Aztec Empire.  Forgetting the subjugated nations they took over, what kept the core of Aztec "citizens" together to attack others, if not a notion of belonging?
Or the Roman Empire.  Rome expanded by taking over its neighbors and generally granting them citizenship fairly easily.  It beat Carthage, which was richer and more competently led, at least at first, by being able to levy vast armies of citizens, while Carthage could not and had to rely on mercenaries.
Or to range totally at the other end of the scale, take the Waorani, a notoriously aggressive and violent group of warring peoples in Ecuador.

As with many peoples, the Waorani maintain a strong in-group/out-group distinction, between Waorani (people who are kin), Waoroni (others in their culture who are unrelated) and Cowodi.

Are they not, in their own worldview, a "nation", even if they don't have much of a choice about Ecuador "owning" their territory?
It takes the French revolution however to gel the notion that you can generally appeal to a higher notion of togetherness and really get masses of people to willingly fight and die for you, for limited monetary gains.  That's a quantum leap forward.
Band them all together and you can define borders that are more stable and continuous over the generations than the old arrangements, as these people expect to be formally together, as one.
That's the rise of Nationalism, which is not exactly the same notion and is somewhat more deserving of invented-in-the-West vanity.

Nationalism is a modern movement. Throughout history people have been attached to their native soil, to the traditions of their parents, and to established territorial authorities, but it was not until the end of the 18th century that nationalism began to be a generally recognized sentiment molding public and private life and one of the great, if not the greatest, single determining factors of modern history. Because of its dynamic vitality and its all-pervading character, nationalism is often thought to be very old; sometimes it is mistakenly regarded as a permanent factor in political behaviour. Actually, the American and French revolutions may be regarded as its first powerful manifestations. After penetrating the new countries of Latin America, it spread in the early 19th century to central Europe and from there, toward the middle of the century, to eastern and southeastern Europe. At the beginning of the 20th century, nationalism flowered in Asia and Africa. Thus, the 19th century has been called the age of nationalism in Europe, while the 20th century witnessed the rise and struggle of powerful national movements throughout Asia and Africa.

That notion, once leveraged, does not really rely on democracy however.  Stalin deployed it perfectly well to fight the Nazis during WW2.
Abroad, one could also say that European subjugation during colonialism also gelled together groups of people to expel them.  India was a number of warring kingdoms before the English subjugated them but came out of it as a nation in every sense of the word.  Well, 2 and then 3, counting Pakistan and Bangladesh.  (It was Kashmir's great misfortune that its ruler decided to go against his people's nationalist sentiments and impose his personal will, but that would have been a lot less exceptional in the past).

There is another dimension on which many modern nations diverge from at least some of their historical predecessors.  To quote from a comment on the companion question @ SE.Philosophy:

What about all the folks who refer to "First Nations"? The usage absolutely fits your definition of: "a group of people who see themselves as a cohesive and coherent unit based on shared cultural or historical criteria".

Well (and this contradicts my Waorini example somewhat), one key thing to consider is that the "First Nations" also often refer to themselves as "Tribes" or "Bands" (it took me while after moving to Canada to be comfortable with referring to them as Tribes, but they themselves often do).
These groups are mostly bloodline-based.  You can get adopted or marry into them and have your children become members but it's not that common.  Whereas, a great many modern nations have legal procedures in place to become full-fledged citizens.  That separates them from many earlier groups, and especially those that are tribal-based.  That there is intense friction with regards to the level of immigration considered desirable, or discrimination against visible minorities doesn't change the fact that many countries/nations have moved past bloodline/ancestry-based criteria for group membership.

So, it seems to me that one could argue that modern Europeans did modify the meaning of nationhood but it certainly existed before.
This seems, at the end, to be purely a matter of opinion and the exact definition of "nation" used.  That some make careers out of discussing it does not overmuch change that.

p.s. A related notion is the recent appearance of nations which did not exist previously due to their territory having been under an external imperial hegemony:  Middle Europe vis a vis the Austro-Hungarian Empire or the Middle East with the Ottoman Empire.  That they are individual countries/nations now, running their own affairs, isn't due to some "civilizing influence" benevolently emanating from European Enlightenment, is it?  Nor is their previous absence all that significant on a cultural/political level.

Agreed. People who revere Europe—and even a certain subset of those who despise it as well, ironically—have a tendency to give it credit for inventing far too many things. The first passport? French, obviously, and the Israelite, Chinese, Indian and Islamic documents that came before obviously must not count for various reasons. The first democracy? Obviously either the USA or Athens, and the evidence of contemporaneous democratic systems of government, or even earlier ones, has to be brushed aside—they were actually oligarchies, or too small to count, or....

Nation-states? Well, obviously created by the Treaty of Westphalia. The Treaty of Chanyuan? Well, it clearly does not count for...reasons.

Yup, odd that people get so far with True Scotsmen to slice and dice the "nation" criteria until they fit just so.

@Obie2.0 History is written by those who write history and who's stories are read.

It was the British who subjugated India, not the English.

@Obie2.0 Do you imply that there were two Chinese nations in the Middle Ages?

This is really fundamentally wrong. This overloading of the word "nation" to mean a "country" is a veryt modern thing mostly used in English in USA and perhaps also in the UK. But the question is obviously about nations etnographic and political units  that consider themselves to be somehow relative typically by common language or descent/origin. Saying that there were countries therefore there were nations, Q.E.D. is just wrong. Yes, there certainly were nations around the aristocracy more tied to medieval countries, but it takes more to show that than this handwaveing.

BTW, despite all those sayings that all nationalism is modern and only originates in the 18th century you will certainly find clear nationalism in medieval works, like, e.g., the clear anti-German (in terms of language, not just country!) nationalism in the 14th century Dalimils chronicle (it became quite popular in Germany anyway).

"Political units existed, had a defined territory, raised taxes and fought wars. If not nations, then what would those be?" They were countries and just that, not nations in sense 1 at wiki. Often somehow united under some ruler and held together by his rule only. But they contained people of many origins, languages, even religions. Especially in the antiquity. The ancient Egypt might be an exception, united by the shared culture, language and religion.

@VladimirFГероямслава Since it's "fundamentally wrong", why not write an answer instead of arguing so much?  And relying so much on your fine tuning of the meaning and history of words (contrary to what you claim, the exact same words variations, pays/nation exist in French as well - I'm French).

@ItalianPhilosopher In France indeed the development went on to define the French nation based on the country, no matter what language did the person speak (French, Gascon, Alsace or even Arab). Tjat is however very different from what happened in other areas of Europe where countries were very much multi-national, mostly based on the languages the populations spoke. The German Empire, The Austria-Hungary, The Russian Empire, The Ottoman Empire, none of them followed France in this and later they dissolved into smaller countries based on the modern nations that consituted in the 18-19 century.

@VladimirFГероямслава Like I said, more than enough verbiage to write an answer.  Which users can upvote or not.  It's easy to criticize without bringing in your own answer.

@ItalianPhilosopher And despite me not mentioning that was not really "contrary to what you claim", I was well aware of the fact, there just was not enough space to go  into all intricacies. And as a non-speaker of French I was not aware to how much that the way how French nation constituted is bound to the definition of the word nation in the French language.

That’s not what the author claims
“… which found their modern form in the last two hundred years or so …”
The claim is that nations in their “modern form” are about 200 years old; not that nations are only 200 years old. The first position is at least arguable (although I would say 400 years rather than 200); the second is obviously untenable.

But then everything has its modern form in only the last [arbitrary number] [unit of time]. If it was not that recent, it would not be counted as "modern"! Which really shows how totally pointless the claim or the discussion is.

@Nij Very good point. In effect, the authors could have said "how nations look has changed since the 1700s or so" but that would be a much less spectacular truism ;-).

@Nij sure, but that doesn’t make the claim an ahistorical one. You state your thesis that the modern form (as you define it) was achieved [unit of time] ago and provide evidence to support it. That’s pretty much the who discipline of history.

The claim about "modern form" is that the allegiances were by aristocrats, but that ordinary people didn't identify as having membership in a "nation". But while this may have been true for some principalities in Europe in the Middle Ages, it was not true, for example, of Slavic or Germanic tribes, or of many other pre-modern nation-states.

@ohwilleke there are lots of things one could point to as being preconditions for a “modern” nation. I haven’t read the book so I don’t know what this particular author considers essential.

@DaleM I recall reading the argument from the book somewhere else and that was how it was summarized.

The proposition sounds increasingly bizarre on additional reflection.
A read through the Old Testament identifies numerous "people groups" who could be excluded from nation status only by the most unusual mental gymnastics.
The "nation of Israel" is only one such - more or less so at various times but eg under the Kings Saul / David / Solomon / ... , they seem to meet all the claimed requirements of the cited paper.

Other examples include:
San Marino:
The Republic / State / Nation / Country of San Marino has existed incontestably as early as 1631 AD and according to some accounts sonce 301 AD.
See Wikipedia - San Marino

" ... The first attested government structure was composed of a self-governed assembly known as the Arengo, which consisted of the heads of each family (as in the original Roman Senate, the Patres). In 1243, the positions of Captains Regent (Capitani Reggenti) were established to be the joint heads of state. The state's earliest statutes date back to 1263. The Holy See confirmed the independence of San Marino in 1631 ... ."


Pacific Island Nations:
The various small Pacific island-group nations  were countries from when a single ruler claimed and achieved "sovereignty", probably not vastly long after they were first populated.
Examples may (or may not) includes Fiji, Tonga, Niue, Rapa Nui, Tokelau and maybe Cook Islands , and more.
Datings unknown, but some and maybe many predate the more recent European manouverings.
Rapanui/ Easter Island was reportedly populated in the 800-1200 AD period.
It would seem hard to deny that Rapanui as a whole did not consititute a nation.
Rapanui - Wikipedia

Experts disagree on when the island's Polynesian inhabitants first reached the island. While many in the research community cited evidence that they arrived around the year 800, a 2007 study found compelling evidence that they arrived closer to 1200. The inhabitants created a thriving and industrious culture, as evidenced by the island's numerous enormous stone moai and other artifacts.


Not every tribe is a nation. Not every population united under some ruler is a nation. There must be some identification of the members of the nation.

Were the Israelites a tribe when they were in the desert in Exodus, or when they were in exile in Babylon? Because that certainly doesn't meet the modern definition of nation. But we don't know how the Israelites felt about their relationship to their ruler and we can't really trust the Bible. The idea of a nation is fundamentally different to a religious community or loyalty to a particular leader.

@StuartF There were 12 tribes of Israel. I haven't checked sources, but I think that the tribe of Benjamin was the first to go to Egypt, and the others followed, so the Israelites collectively were still the 12 tribes during Exodus and the return. Later, I think there are historical records of an area under the control of the tribe of Judah (one of the 12 tribes) in the north of Israel, and two of the other tribes in the south. Regardless, I understand your point, as it is the same as the one made by Saddam Hussain about the only two Middle-Eastern nations being Iraq and Egypt.

I'm surprised but not surprised at the 3 comments so far. Judah qualified as a nation for substantial periods by probably any and all criteria likely to be suggested. When an invader scoops up your leadership lock stock and both smoking barrels and executes some and carries the rest off to a farish country it becomes "difficult to maintain national cohesion"- but Judah (like unto Poland) managed even that long term. || The nation split into two post Solomon - for reasons well described - Judah and Israel. Both were nations by many criteria.


a common government which enacts common rules (i.e. a more or less centralized state), a common language and a common culture, over a common territory, which give this society its unity

First, I'm not sure why you left out common religion, which is very important even today, and which is a poor proxy vis a vis common culture, since you can share a culture with somebody you've just started a schism against.
Second, and the main argument, is that before European modernity, countries did not try to maximize all of these communalities like they did during the European modernity.
There were different rules depending on which estate you belonged to. There were no concerted effort to make sure peasants speak exactly the same language used in the houses of the noble, much less in the church. Said nobility and clerics having way more common with their peers across the borders, than with peasants or small townsfolk of their specific country. Even the territory could be fragmented, with church lands and feudalism and principalities.
It is only during the European modernity that countries saw the necessity of maximizing all of these sliders, which were not at zero before that, but were at some relaxed values. This also definitely did not happen overnight, neither the process is finished completely and everywhere, and arguably there were even some reverse movements.

There were a great many wars in Europe to impose religious homogeneity, after the arrival of Protestantism broadened the options beyond uni-Catholicism and before European modernity.  Germany's 30 Years War, Dutch-Spanish War 80 Years War.

That does not run contrary to anything I wrote.

You wrote: countries did not try to maximize all of these communalities.  They did, at least on religious matters.  No DV, just a qualification of your claim.  However, regarding linguistics, you are correct, at least in France.  Modern French was very much imposed on the regions after the Revolution.

They've actually switched from applying pressure on the religious slider, to moving all of the other sliders mentioned in the question, which proved fruitful.

The current trends of nationalism and the notion of the nation-state are about that old, yes. That's painting with a broad brush, but that's not an uncommon statement in IR and comparative politics circles.
Nations have existed for a long time, and indeed the author doesn't claim otherwise: "Nations are units of identity and organization which found their modern form in the last two hundred years or so."
Before the 1800s there were Italians, for example. But there were Italians were were part of the Austro-Hungarian Empire, Italians were part of the French Empire, Italians who were subjects of the Papal States, Kingdoms of Sardinia and the Two Sicilies, etc.
Italy, the nation of people, existed, and Italians understood themselves to be a part of it. But no one adamantly believed that there should be a singular Italian state whose borders encompass all those who understand themselves to be Italian.
That didn't really take off in a big way until after the Enlightenment and American and French Revolutions began to weaken the longstanding understanding that statehood was inexplicably tied to monarchy and lordship over domains. Once you begin to believe that the French crown isn't a paramount, God-given institution, what even is the French state, and why should anyone be loyal to it? The answer, it turns out, is "an institution of the French people," and you should be loyal to it because "we are French."
Revolutions happened all over in 1848, and in many of Europe's multiethnic empires, they almost by necessity took on a distinctly nationalist tone. If a Prague republican believes they should be ruled "by the people," the natural question is "what people"? The only thing tying them to the people of Vienna, Budapest, Venice, etc. is they happened to be ruled by the same guy in a robe. So the natural answer wasn't "the Austro-Hungarian people," it was "the Czech people."
Not all the nationalist movements succeeded and there are a quite few nations that are still stateless (Breton, Catalans, etc.). But even the modern independence movements are still pushes for a single "nation-states" would have been a relatively foreign concept before democracy became the hot new thing.

I am (utterly) no expert on such things BUT my reading of a little of San Marino's history really makes me feel that they very much considered themself a nation - state / republic / country / .... well before 1631 - when the Holy See confirmed their independence.  || See my answer - above dates from Wikipedia - San Marino . ||...

...  They say " ...  In 1243, the positions of Captains Regent (Capitani Reggenti) were established to be the joint heads of state. The state's earliest statutes date back to 1263.. ..." --> I very strongly suspect that THEY considered themselves "the real deal" even if we don't.

No.
For the easiest counterexample,the Holy Roman Empire started being called the HRE of the German Nation, Sacrum Imperium Romanum Nationis Germanicae  unofficially in the 15th century and officially since 1512, so people certainly thought of Germans as a nation back then already.
The Nation State, i.e. all the members of a nation are under one state and members of other nations must assimilate into the primary nation or leave, is a 19th century idea, but that's distinct from the idea of a nation.

I remember some old texts about fighters working in "outsourcing" for some Swiss cantons. It is in the early XIV. century. They used the word "Germans" for the Swiss.

However, this Empire contained kingdoms of inhabited and ruled by people of different nations or language. E.g., the Kingdom of Bohemia (at least by 1512 still not ruled by the Gemans/Austrians yet).

You implicitly limit the concept of nation to ethnicity (which is a widespread misconception in former Marxist countries), whereas this is only one of the possible options. A nation is a large political community united around some kind of consensus, that's all.

The Holy Roman Empire was not a nation in the modern sense of the word (or, really, the historic sense of the word either).  It consisted of the Emperor's personal fief, plus as many of the Germanic principalities as he could threaten or persuade to follow his lead.

@Mark it was not a state, in the modern sense, certainly, but Germans as a people considered themselves a nation, even in the 16th century, same way the Kurds consider themselves a nation, despite being split among multiple states.

@Eugene The Germans mostly did, but the empire really contained peoples of other (sometimes-yet-to-be-consituted) nations.

@VladimirFГероямслава of course the empire contained other people's, that's the definition of bring an empire, rolling foreign peoples. But it was officially recognized that the German Nation ran the thing.

@Eugene It is not so simple. The king of Bohemia was one of the kurfurst since a long time before adding the suffix, it is not that the Germans simply ruled there.

Even earlier there was actually a Kingdom of Germany but that was only a part of the Holy Roman Empire https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Germany

First, let me break some terms down:

'Nation' is a term that applies to people(s). It's a modern extension of the ancient concept of a 'tribe' or 'clan': people who are loosely and generally related by heritage, religion, culture, language, or other common identity features.
'State' is a term that applies to administration(s). It's a modern extension of the ancient concept of 'kingdom' or 'empire', where one group controls and administers a territory, including all of the disparate people(s) that live within it. Historically kingdoms (not to mention empires) were not overly concerned with who lived within their borders, so long as those people(s) paid their taxes, obeyed edicts, and kept their noses clean.
'Country' is a term that applies to land. It's an identification with a region that one resides in, a modern extension of the ancient concept of the agricultural city-state. At heart, 'country' refers to the place we live, work, have friends, make families, all delimited by the our limitations in daily travel.

The problem with these terms is that historically they were more-or-less aligned. Agricultural and pastoral tribes lived in given regions and didn't move around that much, so country and nation were more-or-less conjoined, and while there might be remote administration from a king or empire, that generally didn't have a huge effect on normal people's lives or on local administrations. Does a farming village in Iberia or its headman care whether their tithe goes to a Roman Emperor or a Gaulish King? In general ancient kingdoms and empires merely coopted local administrations.
This started to change a bit with the introduction of large-scale monotheistic religion, which unified peoples along new and broad theocratic lines, but the real kicker was advances in transportation technology starting in the early Colonial era. Administrations began to project power faster and wider; people(s) dispersed, expanded their range, and intermingled with far away peoples; people's conception of homeland expanded from what one can reach in a day on foot or by horse to what one can reach in a day by ship or (eventually) rail.  This expansion and intermingling created a bit of a panic among both administrative entities and the (tribal) leadership of people(s), who wanted to define more clearly who and what they had control over. So the concepts of 'state' and 'nation' came into being. Rather than having (say) a Frankish king who basically ruled over whatever people happened to live in the territory the king's military managed to control, the concept of 'France' was reified to refer to a given territory (a country), the people in that territory were reified as 'French' regardless of origin (a nation), and the king was reconciled as its rightful administrative head (a state). This allowed European states to expand colonially into far-flung regions while maintaining a core identity. The nation-state was invented to unify people, state, and country in a world where such were rapidly disintegrating due to sheer mobility.
We should be a little careful when we start thinking about non-European exemplars, because they have been retroactively redefined by Western Colonials. Pre-colonial China and India, for instance, were both ancient empires as laid out above: an administrative center loosely ruling over a number of distinct peoples each with their own local administrations. However, European Colonial nations interacted with them each as a single people with a single state — imposing, and even enforcing, the European nation-state model — and that understanding has stuck within Western historical understanding. The Japanese might be an interesting exception, but only because their geographic isolation made them a more homogenous people than typically found in empires.
The next development, of course, is nationalism: an effort to recreate primitive tribalism within the modern administrative state. People who talk about the nation-state in that mode are quite dangerous. But that's a different topic…

A mistake of the argumentation of Italian Phylosopher is that languages change. Particularly the words "nation", "people", "country" and "state" are similar or usable in mostly similar contexts. Also the societies change, for example it is possible to interpret "nation" only as the nobility of the country. And most importantly, the things and concepts, for which these words were used, changed the most.
Beside that, as the languages of the official documents (and very often, also the official language of the state) was latin, various latin terminologies were used as well. We are talking about a millenium long history of a continent.
Note that part of the problems still today exist. For example, the USA government terminology is using the word "nation" as the land where you are citizen. For example, north and south korea are different nations in this view, while the reality is that they are the same nation divided between two states.
However, history is roughly objective in this sense. The count of various written remembers and documents could fulfill libraries.
I remember the citizens of the Boston Teaparty, risking an UK military intervention and then execution by hanging at the time. They had been probably quite surprised if they learn, they are risking their life for some social construct. No, they have created the nation of the USA. But I could also remember the fighters of the various wars against various, mostly muslim incursions. Their remembers, in written historical documents, are tremendous and they have clearly died for their nation - even if the word was not used, or entirely different words were used for that at the time (note that at the time, even English was only a small language of a cold, far island).
In short, nations have always existed, already the Roman Empire had them. With our words, the Roman Empire was a multi-national autocratic state. But instead of the word "nation", many different names were used, depending on the language and on the political or sociological situation. Contrary, the idea of their non-existence is a XX. century neoliberal invention.
